Does a Wizard with a Beguiler dip learn Beguiler spells when gaining Wizard levels?
Sort of the reverse of an older question I posed here before.
The Beguiler learns (most) spells in a pecular manner:

Spells: A beguiler casts arcane spells, which are drawn from the beguiler spell list. When you gain access to a new level of spells, you automatically know all the spells for that level on the beguiler's spell list. You can cast any spell you know without preparing it ahead of time. Essentially, your spell list is the same as your spells known list.

This does not specify HOW the character gains access to a new level of spells. Which, indubitably, a Wizard does while levelling.
So, the question is; does a Beguiler 1/Wizard 3, upon gaining access to 2nd level spells through the Wizard class, automatically know all 2nd level spells on the Beguiler's spell list?
Note: I cut out the part about the Wizard then copying that spell into the Wizard's spellbook, as this answer to another question indicates that to not be as clear-cut as I thought. This answer points to Versatile Spellcaster as an alternate way to leverage any extra spells known.

I'm surprised that the quoted sentence generated this question when the sentence immediately after that one says, "You can cast any spell you know without preparing it ahead of time" (Player's Handbook 2 6). That next sentence (also taken in isolation) should make a 1-level dip in beguiler mandatory for clerics, druids, and wizards. Seriously: Is that already the case in your campaigns? Because if so, that's cool, but can the question include that information? I worry that answers may try to point you to how they play rather than how it seems that you might actually be playing.

Sorry, I tried to focus on the relevant text, assuming most anyone answering would have access to the Beguiler class in full. I wasn't sure if the class and text are part of the SRD.

If this was written in a feat, it would work that way.
But since it’s written as a class feature, it’s specific to beguiler. It’s

when you gain access to a new level of spells [as a beguiler], you automatically know [as a beguiler] all the spells for that level on the beguiler’s spell list.

This is not clearly spelled out anywhere, but the entire game runs on this kind of logic. The glossary entry for level hints at it:

class level: A character’s level in a single class. Class features generally depend on class level rather than character level.

(Player’s Handbook, pg. 306)
Despite this statement, class features rarely say “class level”—they mostly just say “level.” It’s supposed to be understood as “class level” in the context of a class feature. Likewise, when spells say “level”—and they usually do—they mean “caster level.”
Finally, one of the primary reasons to be a beguiler/wizard is to ban enchantment and illusion as a wizard, since beguiler is so strong in those schools. But the wording of the wizard’s school specialty feature has the same problem that the beguiler’s spells known does:

Spells of the prohibited school or schools are not available to the wizard, and she can’t even cast such spells from scrolls or fire them from wands.

(Player’s Handbook, pg. 57)
And yet we know that a sorcerer/wizard can learn sorcerer spells of their prohibited wizard schools.
In short, this kind of thing is everywhere in the rules. Not even the most theoretical of theoretical optimizers claims that it’s valid to interpret them that literally.

Implicit rules are the worst, to me. I note the "weasel" term "generally" in the quote on class levels, which makes that quote generally unhelpful to me, when I attempt to interpret things on my own. Anyway, thanks for the assist!
